# Ignore lines in a file till match and process lines after that

Tags: perl

I am looping over lines in a file and when matched a particular line, i want to process the lines after the current (matched) line. I can do it :-

```
open my $fh, '<', "abc" or die "Cannot open!!"; 
while (my $line = <$fh>){
   next if($line !~ m/Important Lines below this Line/);
   last;
}
while (my $line = <$fh>){
   print $line;
}
```

Is there a better way to do this (code needs to be a part of a bigger perl script) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd use [flip-flop operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators):

```
while(<DATA>) {
    next if 1 .. /Important/;
    print $_;
}
__DATA__
skip
skip
Important Lines below this Line
keep
keep
```

**output:**

```
keep
keep
```

Comment: Any idea why it does doesn't work with looping over lines in file(like the one shown in my example)?

Comment: @VineetDeoraj No, it should work with any file handle. If it does not, you did something wrong.

Comment: @M42 You should perhaps point out that the `1` in the flip-flop is actually a line number (`$. == 1`), so the flip-flop will "open" for line #1, but once closed will remain closed until eof.

Comment: @VineetDeoraj I take it you had passed line #1 in your file handle? This method needs a fresh file handle because of the `1` limitation. But you could reverse it instead: `print if /Important/ .. eof;` Which is to say: when you find the match, print until end of file.

Comment: @TLP : `/(*FAIL)/`, `/(*F)/` and `/(?!)/` are other ways to ensure the flip never flops :)

Comment: @Zaid eof is more intuitive, though.